# How to map an element based on url ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say that I have an array of objects that looks like

```
[{
details:
   {id: 7},
type: minigame1,
...(blabla some other values that i'll have to access later)
},
{
details:
  {id: 8},
type: minigame1,
...(blabla some other values that i'll have to access later)
},
{
details:
  {id: 10},
type: minigame2,
...
}]
```

now, the link to my component is based on these values, so lets say I choose the first mini game, I get routed to localhost/minigame1/7

the link works, although I only figured out a temporary solution, to actually get the certain, chosen minigame data.

```
if (taskData !== '') {
    minigameData = taskData
      .filter(t => t.type === 'minigame1')
      .map(el => {
        questionsData = el;
      });
  }
```

this although ignores the id and only pulls data for the first game it can find (with id 7), even if i choose the one with id 8.
So I tried to use the good ol

```
let { id } = useParams();
```

My problem is, I'm not sure how to make it filter the game data through the id AND also the game type.

I've tried adding another

```
.filter(t => t.details.id === id)
```

after the first one, but it only caused my data to not load at all, no matter the link id.

I've just spent so much time trying to figure out a solution I just ran out of ideas.

Would be thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter` returns an array of all elements matching the criteria. However, you're only using 1 field when you really need to match the `type` AND the `details.id`. All you need to do is add the 2nd criteria to your return statement.

However, for your use case, I would think that `.find` would be a better choice. Instead of returning an array of all choices, it returns the first one it finds only (since the minigame + id should likely be unique right?), so I've updated your logic below.

```js
if (taskData !== '') {
    minigameData = taskData
      .find(t => t.type === 'minigame1' && t.details.id === id);
  }
```

Lastly, I removed your `.map` at the end as it wasn't doing anything. You weren't returning the value at the end, so I'm not sure what the end result would have been.

If `t.details.id` isn't matching on anything, I'd check what your `params` is returning.

Comment: thank you for such a quick answer! I've tried your solution, still didnt work, so I've tried to compare a t.details.id with a certain number instead of id and it worked. Looks like there must be some issue with types, cuz my next step was just turning the '===' into '==' and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like `id` is a number while the params is a string. If you convert one to the type of the other it would also work.